# Spark <console>:1: error: ';' expected but double literal found

Tags: apache-spark

I am running this line from scala shell

```
scala> spark-sql --jars /usr/local/spark/jars/sqlite-jdbc-3.23.1.jar;
```

My session

```
 spark
res0: org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession = org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession@421f447f
```

Strange problem happens

```
<console>:1: error: ';' expected but double literal found.
spark-sql --jars /usr/local/spark/jars/sqlite-jdbc-3.23.1.jar;
```

If I put quotes

```
scala> spark-sql --jars "/usr/local/spark/jars/sqlite-jdbc-3.23.1.jar";
<console>:1: error: ';' expected but string literal found.
spark-sql --jars "/usr/local/spark/jars/sqlite-jdbc-3.23.1.jar";

                                                       ^
```

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access **`spark-sql cli`** from `scala` terminal,

**Exit** from scala terminal using **`(:q + enter)`**,
Then from bash terminal access `spark-sql` cli

```
bash$ spark-sql --jars "/usr/local/spark/jars/sqlite-jdbc-3.23.1.jar"
```

**`(or)`**

You can initialize spark-shell with the jars then use spark.sql(...) to run your commands.

```
bash$ spark-shell --jars "/usr/local/spark/jars/sqlite-jdbc-3.23.1.jar"
scala> spark.sql("<sql_query>")
```